# GMT Time format to integer format

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to show ticker clock for different timezone. When I looked around the web, it looks like it takes number for the offset(for example +5.5 hours) in javascript. But the way we are getting the gmtformat is +05:30 in php which I am trying to feed in to the javascript function. Is there any function that I can use to convert?

```
/*CLOCK CODE IN JAVASCRIPT*/
function startclock(field, timediff, newOrRepeat)
{ 
    var clockAction=newOrRepeat;
if (timediff=="") {$(field).html("-------");return false;}
    /****THERE ARE MORE STUFF IN BETWEEN AND AFTER WHICH IS NOT RELEVANT TO OFFSET****/
var secondsDiff=0;
var secondsTimeZone = 0;
//calculate the difference in time set by both the timezone as well as the DST
secondsTimeZone = parseInt(timediff);


if ($("input[name='daylight']:checked").val()=="on" && $(field).siblings("#isDaylight").val()=="no")
    secondsDiff=secondsTimeZone + 3600;
else if ($("input[name='daylight']:checked").val()=="off" && $(field).siblings("#isDaylight").val()=="yes")
    secondsDiff=secondsTimeZone - 3600;
else 
    secondsDiff = secondsTimeZone;

var thetime=new Date();

thetime.setUTCSeconds(parseInt(thetime.getUTCSeconds())+parseInt(secondsDiff));
var nhours=thetime.getUTCHours();
var nmins=thetime.getUTCMinutes();
var nsecn=thetime.getUTCSeconds();

}
```

I am getting getting gmt format straight from php which i am passing to this function.

Comment: Whathaveyoutried? Convert what to what. Give examples and code.

Comment: I am trying to convert +05:30 to 5.5.

Comment: You have to extract the integer value after ":" if it is not zero, then divide it over 60. then place the result after ":"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function convert_time($time){
    $parts = explode(':', $time);
    return $parts[0] + number_format($parts[1]/60, 2);
}
```

Comment: i figured that out, but i was looking for a built in php function or javascript function. Nonetheless it works.
Thank you